# Stopping Divs displaying across multiple cells in Excel

Tags: asp.net, html, excel

I am downloading a html document and opening it in excel, in order to create an spreadsheet from a table i have on a webpage by changing the content types to

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename="excel.xls")
```

But i find that some of the rows in my excel are spread over multiple lines, due to the html in the rows themselves (such as line breaks and divs) [the table is created by a repeater and has some interactive components to allow editing etc]
I found here http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1095-Maintaining-Line-Breaks-In-An-HTML-Excel-File.htm how to stop line breaks from splitting over multiple rows, but after implementing this, there are still line breaks appearing in the excel.

Below is the td cell that is causing the splitting. Am i right in thinking it is the  tag that is causing the splitting? Is there an equivilent solution for stopping  tags from splitting, or would it be simpler to just have two different sections, one for when in the UI and one for when in excel?

```
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox id="cbAdjust" runat="server" visible="false" /><br style="mso-data-placement:same-cell;"/>
                <div id="divAdjustments" runat="server" >
                    <div id="divLicAdjust" runat="server" style="mso-data-placement:same-cell;" >
                        License: <asp:Label id="lblAdjustLic" runat="server" text='1' />
                    </div>
                    <div id="divSaasAdjust" runat="server" style="mso-data-placement:same-cell;">
                        Saas: <asp:Label ID="lblAdjustFyr" runat="server" text='2' />
                    </div>
                    <a id="aEditAdjust" runat="server" href="javascript:void(0)" style="height:auto" class="dashboardButton">Edit</a>
                </div>
                <a id="aSaveAdjust" runat="server" href="javascript:void(0)" class="dashboardButton TextBoxBtn">Save</a>               
            </ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: You might want to format and export your tabular data as a [CSV file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) and open that with Excel. You might have a bear of a time getting Excel to do what you want with a file format that is not meant to be used with Excel. Just my $.02.

Comment: In previous places I have used the Epplus library for exporting pages into excel, so that is always an option. more curious to see if there is a way of stopping <div> if there is one to stop <br>